# Does visual studio database project(VSDB) replaced by (SQL Sever Data Tool)SSDT

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, vsdb

Does visual studio database project(VSDB) replaced by SSDT.
Should I build all future projects in SSDT.

Currently my environment is VS2010 and SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. SQL Server Data Tools installs a SQL Server Database Project template which replaces the former database project template. Visual Studio 2010 is supported.